# Can You Have An Exposed Filter In One Page Of A View But Not On Another?

Tags: 7, views

I have a View with two Pages. On the first Page I want to have an Exposed filter for User ID. On the other I want to use a Contextual Filter to dynamically filter a single UID.

Is it possible to do this on one View...

ie. have the Exposed Filter on the first Page Display and the Contextual on the other?

Or do I need to create two similar views to accomplish this?

It seems like I can override the -display- of the Exposed filter but not whether it is applied to the SQL Query.

Comment: So are you wanting the first page to have the filter and the second to take the results of that filter, but not have the exposed filter on that page?

Comment: @chadpeppers, I think jchwebdev meant he has a view with 2 "page" displays. One display should have an exposed filter and another one - contextual filter.

Comment: @chadpeppers You are correct. Sorry, these terms are kinda ambiguous to me yet. I want one View with two 'Displays' of type 'Page'... one with an Exposed Filter and the other with a Contextual Filter. Can do? If so, how?